# Como enviar dados cadastrados

Tags: php

alguém poderia me dar uma luz , estou criando um sisteminha para padaria e tipo nela tem seis computadores e cincos ficam no caixa e um no fundo da padaria . Esses cincos computadores tem uma tela como mostra na imagem abaixo . o que eu quero fazer é quando os clientes escolhem o que vão comprar eu seleciono nessa tela e enviu quero que em outra tela aquele um computador receba o pedido e veja de qual computador enviou . Como posso fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom momento para ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que ter um conhecimento bem básico do PHP.

Se escolher um banco de dados para isso, tem que saber um pouquinho de MySQL/php. Se escolher escrita de arquivo (que acho mais fácil para iniciante), tem que saber o que são permissões de pasta. Baixe uma classe que criei chamada Woop, e deixe na mesma pasta do projeto usado:
https://github.com/paulosergioduff/woop

Como eu faria? Se for de uma forma bem simples, salvo o nome do computador numa REQUEST (dados temporários do navegador).

algo assim:

Cadastra.php

```
<form action="recebeformulario.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="nomeDoComputador"><br>
<text area name="pedido"><br>
<input type="submit" value="cadastrarComputador">
```

recebeformulario.php

```
<?php

$nomeDoComputador = $_GET['nomeDoComputador'];
$pedido = $_GET['pedido'];

include "criarpagina.class.php";
include "formulario.php";
$app = $_POST['funcao'];
    $criarpagina = new criarpagina; /* A função de usar classes e objetos ao invés de variáveis estruturais
    tem mais a ver com didática e organização do código*/
    $criarpagina->pagina = "pedidos" . ".txt"; // Sempre concatene para evitar acesso indevido a outros arquivos
    $criarpagina->conteudo = $nomeDoComputador . " " . $pedido . "
"
;//orinalmente base64_encode($_POST['conteudo']);
    //$criarpagina->arquivoalvo = ';
    $criarpagina->$app();
    //$criarpagina->imprimeXML();

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado deu pra ter uma ideia